# Сериализация и десериализация содержимого TextBlock

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Задача: сериализовать содержимое `TextBlock`'a (чтобы сохранить оригинальное содержимое), изменить и подставить в `TextBlock`.

С сериализацией беда просто. Нашел 2 способа, но оба чем нибудь да не подходят.

Способ 1:

Прохожу по коллекции `Inlines` текстблока и при помощи `XamlWriter.Save(inline)` сохраняю все элементы. Потом восстанавливаю при помощи `XamlReader.Parse(string)`.

Минус тут в том, что `XamlWriter` способен сохранять только те свойства, которые были назначены в рантайме, поэтому, если я наполняю `TextBlock` в дизайнере, все элементы (Run, Span и тд.) сохраняются без свойств и даже без текста. Просто пустыми.

Способ 2:

```
// Текущим элементом тут является `TextBlock`
// _content имеет тип string
var tr = new TextRange(ContentStart, ContentEnd);
using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    tr.Save(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);
    stream.Position = 0;
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        _content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

В текстовом блоке имею вот что

```
<Run Text="{Binding Property}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

в `_content` записывается вот что

```
<Span xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xml:space="preserve" xml:lang="en-us" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="Text" NumberSubstitution.Substitution="AsCulture" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Bold" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF000000" Typography.StandardLigatures="True" Typography.ContextualLigatures="True" Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures="False" Typography.HistoricalLigatures="False" Typography.AnnotationAlternates="0" Typography.ContextualAlternates="True" Typography.HistoricalForms="False" Typography.Kerning="True" Typography.CapitalSpacing="False" Typography.CaseSensitiveForms="False" Typography.StylisticSet1="False" Typography.StylisticSet2="False" Typography.StylisticSet3="False" Typography.StylisticSet4="False" Typography.StylisticSet5="False" Typography.StylisticSet6="False" Typography.StylisticSet7="False" Typography.StylisticSet8="False" Typography.StylisticSet9="False" Typography.StylisticSet10="False" Typography.StylisticSet11="False" Typography.StylisticSet12="False" Typography.StylisticSet13="False" Typography.StylisticSet14="False" Typography.StylisticSet15="False" Typography.StylisticSet16="False" Typography.StylisticSet17="False" Typography.StylisticSet18="False" Typography.StylisticSet19="False" Typography.StylisticSet20="False" Typography.Fraction="Normal" Typography.SlashedZero="False" Typography.MathematicalGreek="False" Typography.EastAsianExpertForms="False" Typography.Variants="Normal" Typography.Capitals="Normal" Typography.NumeralStyle="Normal" Typography.NumeralAlignment="Normal" Typography.EastAsianWidths="Normal" Typography.EastAsianLanguage="Normal" Typography.StandardSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualSwashes="0" Typography.StylisticAlternates="0" BaselineAlignment="Baseline" TextDecorations=""><Run>qwe</Run></Span>
```

То что я сделал, сохранило все форматирование для текущего элемента из родителя и при этом перенесло `FontWeight="Bold"` в общий стиль. То есть в этом случае у меня есть 2 варианта:

1. Обрезать общие стили и потерять вместе с ними заданное форматирование
2. Оставить все как есть, но это всплывет, если во время выполнения кто то поменяет в текстблоке какой то стиль.

Что делать не знаю. Вариант 2.2 наиболее подходящий, но все равно кривой. Время выполнения кода так же имеет значение, поэтому "пробежаться по всем свойствам оригинала и включить/исключить в результат" не предлагать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный момент есть такое решение (текущий объект - `TextBlock`):

```
var sp = new Span();
sp.Inlines.AddRange(Inlines.ToArray());
var tr = new TextRange(sp.ContentStart, sp.ContentEnd);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    tr.Save(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);
    stream.Position = 0;
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        _content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
Inlines.AddRange(sp.Inlines.ToArray());
```

То есть сначала создаем `Span`, заполняю его из текстового блока и его уже сохраняю. В этом случае все свойства форматирования элементов внутри сохраняются.